# IEquatable implementation and operator overriding

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, abstract-class, iequatable

A domain class `T` can be of type `ValueObject<T>`:

```
public class Coordinate: ValueObject<Coordinate>
{ ... }
```

`ValueObject<T>` implements the `IEquatable` interface.  I want each concrete implementation of `ValueObject<T>` to provide implementation for `bool Equals(T obj)`, so I have created it as an abstract method:

```
public abstract class ValueObject<T> : IEquatable<T>
{
    public abstract bool Equals(T obj);

    public static bool operator ==(ValueObject<T> obj1, ValueObject<T> obj2)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2)) return true;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, null)) return false;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj2, null)) return false;

        return obj1.Equals(obj2);
    }
}
```

An Equals implementation in the `Coordinate` class:

```
public class Coordinate : ValueObject<Coordinate>
{
    // ...

    public override bool Equals(Coordinate other)
    {
        return (other != null) && (this.Latitude == other.Latitude) && (this.Longitude == other.Longitude);
    }
}
```

`ValueObject<T>` provides generic operating overriding for == (and for !=, which is not shown above), which applies to all concrete implementations.

The problem is that when the `Equals` method is called from either the == override, it calls `Object.Equals()` and not `Coordinate.Equals()`.

Comment: So what causes `Coordinate` to override `Equals(object)` to keep it consistent with `Equals<Coordinate>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The problem is that when the `Equals` method is called from either the `==` override, it calls `Object.Equals()` and not `Coordinate.Equals()`.

No, the problem is that *those things are different*. If they are the same, as they should be, then there's no problem.

So make them the same. Don't make the derived class do the wrong thing; **force them to do the right thing**.

```
public abstract class ValueObject<T> : IEquatable<T>
{
    // Force the derived class to override these.
    public abstract override bool Equals(object obj);
    public abstract override int GetHashcode(object obj);

    // And then consistently use the overridden method as the implementation.
    public virtual bool Equals(T obj)
    {
        return obj1.Equals((object)obj2);
    }
    public static bool operator ==(ValueObject<T> obj1, ValueObject<T> obj2)
    {
         return obj1.Equals((object)obj2);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(ValueObject<T> obj1, ValueObject<T> obj2)
    {
         return !obj1.Equals((object)obj2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has a cleaner public surface but has less code sharing on the inside. In fact, this version of `ValueObject<T>` almost accomplishes nothing. The signature of `==` is still wrong because it allows any `ValueObject<T>` which is too general. Although the surface is now cleaner than before, this approach is still not viable to be exposed publicly from a library.

Comment: @Eric: I understand my mistake now.  Although now, in my concrete implementations, I will have to override a weaker `Equals(object)` which means casting will need to occur (i.e. I will need to cast `object` to `Coordinate` in order to compare properties).  My initial attempt was to force a more specific `Equals(T)`.

Comment: @usr: Sure, it's still messed up in a bunch of ways.

Comment: @davenewza: Well you're going to have to override `Equals(object)` at some point so there is no avoiding the type test.  An object has to be comparable to every other object, no getting around it. It's unfortunate.

Comment: Your == and != operators have the same formula.

Comment: @LarsTech: Whoops! Thanks for noticing that. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `obj1.Equals(obj2)`, `obj2` is of type `ValueObject<T>` which does not match the `T` in `public abstract bool Equals(T obj)`.

In fact, at runtime it could be of a different class than `T`.

Probably, you want to return false in that case.

```
public static bool operator ==(ValueObject<T> obj1, ValueObject<T> obj2)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2)) return true;
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, null)) return false;
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj2, null)) return false;
    if (obj1.GetType() != obj2.GetType()) return false; //new

    return ((T)(object)obj1).Equals((T)(object)obj2);
}
```

I think you indend that `T` is equal to a derived class of `ValueObject<T>`. You can say `where T : ValueObject<T>`. That encodes at least a part of what you want in the type system and saves you the `(object)` cast.

Comment: It is allowed but it doesn't do what you want it to. When you say `class V<T> where T : V<T> {} class C : V<C> {}` then `C` matches the pattern, but what stops you from then saying `class D : V<C>` ? Now it doesn't match the pattern. The pattern you want actually cannot be represented in the C# type system; try Haskell if you want a type system that can represent that.

Comment: @EricLippert yeah I think it does save the `(object)` cast, though. Fewer contortions required.

Comment: So the idea is to add a confusing constraint to the public surface of the object in order to save typing eight characters as the implementation details of a method?

Comment: @EricLippert mostly to exclude a few invalid uses/mistakes. This pattern is dirty, anyway. We agree that it is impossible to implement it in a clean way. Btw, it's 16 characters! :)